# count occurrences in pipe delimited string in dataframe

Tags: r, count

I have a Names column in my dataframe as follows:

```
Names             
steve|chris|jeff     
melissa|jo|john
chris|susan|redi
john|fiona|bart
jo|chris|fiona
```

The entries are pipe delimited. Is there a way to count the occurrences of the names in this column? For example, Chris occurs 3 times. Using a package like "plyr" works when there are only single entries in the column, but not sure about entries that are combined like above.

Comment: I think you want `table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$Names), "|", fixed = TRUE)))`

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!